# How to use call echo in a string

Tags: batch-file, cmd, menu, set, call

I am using a menu and want to write to a file with selected name in dropdown. It's working fine except the file name is incorrect.

It's naming it " ws-%Name[2]% " and not putting the correct value in.
How can I fix this this? thanks for any help

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO Select Postroom staff:-
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.

set "Name[1]=Diana Mckinley"
set "Name[2]=Lenka Smolkova"
set "Name[3]=Louise Smith"
set "Name[4]=Sally Baldwin"
set "Name[5]=Sally Faulkner"
set "Name[6]=Sarah Kendle"
set "Name[7]=Sophie Jennings"
set "Name[8]=Steven Caylor"

:MenuLoop
set /a "x+=1"
if defined Name[%x%] (
    call echo   %x%. %%Name[%x%]%%
    goto MenuLoop
)

ECHO.

SET /P index=Type KEY then press ENTER to register:

call echo %%Name[%index%]%% is now registered

call echo %%Name[%index%]%% > "C:\Users\karim ali\Documents\Test\ws-%%Name[%index%]%%.txt"

GOTO MenuLoop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you'll need to do is to set that name and index as a variable and use that.

Here is an example with a few changes for demonstation purposes:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "Name[1]=Diana Mckinley"
SET "Name[2]=Lenka Smolkova"
SET "Name[3]=Louise Smith"
SET "Name[4]=Sally Baldwin"
SET "Name[5]=Sally Faulkner"
SET "Name[6]=Sarah Kendle"
SET "Name[7]=Sophie Jennings"
SET "Name[8]=Steven Caylor"

:MENU
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO Select Postroom staff:-
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.

:MenuLoop
FOR /F "TOKENS=2-3 DELIMS==[]" %%A IN ('SET Name[') DO (
    CALL ECHO   %%A. %%Name[%%A]%%)
ECHO.
SET /P index=Type KEY then press ENTER to register:
CALL SET "PRSName=%%Name[%index%]%%"
ECHO.
ECHO %PRSName% is now registered
TIMEOUT 2 /NOBREAK 1>NUL
ECHO %PRSName%>"C:\Users\karim ali\Documents\Test\ws-%PRSName%.txt"
SET "Name[%index%]="
SET Name[>NUL 2>&1&&(GOTO :MENU)
```

Answer (score 0):

expansion of nested variables can be confusing...

instead of `ws-%%Name[%index%]%%.txt`, write `ws-%Name[%%index%%]%.txt`